# Select available and unavalible slots from three mysql tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have three tables which fill out a grid of slots it shows available and unavailable slots against room and time.
The tables and the relations are as below:

[image: relational tables]

Classes can be active or inactive. In my query i want to show alll active classes and free slots which are kept in class_info table.
My query here shows all including active and inactive.

```
SELECT * FROM class_info 
LEFT JOIN class_slots ON class_slots.class_info_id = class_info.class_info_id 
LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = class_slots.class_id
WHERE active = 1
```

I would like to be able to show only active class and those that dont exist as free slots.

Some class will become inactive after a time period however I would like to keep it as history, when this becomes inactive the slots become free and are no longer needed to be shown with the query above all are shown even if it is inactive.

**UPDATE:**

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83c37/1)

What I would like is for all class_info rows to show always and IF any class_id exists in class_slots which are active that to show too. At the moment it is only showing those that are active (active = 1) and none from the class_info side. Keeping in mind that in future some class will become inactive (active = 0).

I am not using date as a timestamp as it is not calculating anything neither will it do in the future.

If I run thise query then all rows are shown including active = 0 which I dont want.

```
SELECT * FROM class_info 
LEFT JOIN class_slots ON class_slots.class_info_id = class_info.class_info_id 
LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = class_slots.class_id
```

With the above query I am half way there.

Here's what I would like:

```
 CLASS_INFO_ID | ROOM_NO |      TIME | CLASS_ID | ACTIVE | TEACHER_ID | START_DATE 
---------------|---------|-----------|----------|--------|------------|------------
             2 |       1 |      11-1 |        2 |      1 |     (null) |     (null) 
             3 |       1 |       2-4 |        3 |      1 |     (null) |     (null) 
             4 |       1 |       4-6 |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null) 
             5 |       1 | 6.30-8.30 |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null) 
             6 |       1 |    Sunday |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null) 
             7 |       2 |      9-11 |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null) 
             8 |       2 |      11-1 |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null) 
             9 |       2 |       2-4 |   (null) | (null) |     (null) |     (null)
```

TRUNCATED result.

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? Why is it insufficient?

Comment: why is `time` in class_info table VARCHAR(45)?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: You need those, `WHERE class_slots.active = 1 AND class_info.time > ` greater then some value in past? class_info.time contain [unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Comment: @Strawberry Updated thanks wasnt aware of sqlfiddle.

Comment: OK, but maybe you missed the part where I WAS SHOUTING? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry hope fully this is what you mean, I've updated.

Comment: Have yoy tried `WHERE class_slots.active = 1 OR class_slots.active is null` ?

Comment: @kordirko I have tried that however it doesn't retrieve those that are not is use anymore. I found the right query after much looking and thinking, I'm posting it below

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct query that retrieves all the rows that I require. It worked by moving the where clause before the second join as part of the first join.

```
SELECT * FROM class_info LEFT JOIN class_slots ON class_slots.class_info_id =
class_info.class_info_id AND active = 1 LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id =
class_slots.class_id
```

Updated  [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83c37/38)

This way all those that are occupied are retrieved as well as those that aren't.

Thanks to all for the pointers.